# How to change entire body background color when hovering over a submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, hover

I've found solutions (see here http://jsfiddle.net/zN983/1/) for creating this event when using a div, but making it happen with a submit button seems to be tricky.

I'm trying to make the whole body background behind the content transition into black when hovering over the Log In button.

What would also be nice is making any black text on the page turn white in the process.

Here's what I'm working with http://jsfiddle.net/63d5R/8/

HTML:

```
    div id="login">



 <body bgcolor="#ffffff" link="#000000" vlink="#FF0000">    <font style="font-size: 70;" face="Courier new">Freddy&nbsp;<font style="font-size: 30;" face="courier new"> ARCHIVE</center></font></font>
</div>
<div class="archiveLogin">
    <center>
        <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="php/processLogin.php" method="post">
            <table width="250" border="0" style="text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font face="FontName, Arial" size="1">USER</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input style="background: black; color: white; " type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font face="FontName, Arial" size="1">PASSWORD</font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <div id="hover">
                        <td>
                            <input style="background: black; color: white;" type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input" value="" size="20" />
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" class="loginButtonBodyBG" id="buttonText" value="Log In" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
</div>
```

/* CSS */

```
    #login {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 75;
    z-index: 2;
}

 .archiveLogin {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
input, textarea, select, a {
    outline: none;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: courier new;
    font-size: x-small;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    font-family: courier new;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-family: courier new;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: courier new;
}

 input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px black inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
}
#password {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#buttonText {
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 23px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
    padding-right: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 123px;
    color: white;
    opacity:1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
#buttonText:hover {
    background-color: rgba(165, 122, 255, 0.7);
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you can make it so:

```
var button = document.getElementById('buttonText');
button.onmouseover = function(e) {
  document.body.style.background = "#000000";
  document.body.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
};
button.onmouseout = function(e) {
  document.body.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  document.body.style.color = "#000000";
};
```

UPDATE: upgrade for smooth effect

```
lerp = function(a,b,u) {
    return (1-u) * a + u * b;
};

fade = function(element, property, start, end, duration) {
    var interval = 10;
    var steps = duration/interval;
    var step_u = 1.0/steps;
    var u = 0.0;
    var theInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if (u >= 1.0){ clearInterval(theInterval) }
        var r = parseInt(lerp(start.r, end.r, u));
        var g = parseInt(lerp(start.g, end.g, u));
        var b = parseInt(lerp(start.b, end.b, u));
        var colorname = 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
        element.style.setProperty(property, colorname);
        u += step_u;
    }, interval);
};

var black_col = {r:  0, g:  0, b:  0};
var white_col   = {r:255, g:255, b:255};
var button = document.getElementById('buttonText');

button.onmouseover = function(e) { 
  fade(document.body,'background',white_col,black_col,2000);
  fade(document.body,'color',black_col,white_col,2000);
};
button.onmouseout = function(e) {
  fade(document.body,'background',black_col,white_col,2000);
  fade(document.body,'color',white_col,black_col,2000);

};
```

Comment: This is great!!! I would love to be able to make it a smoother slower transition.

Comment: Upgrade for smooth transition.

Comment: @user3697526 you may also mind to upvote answers when it brings you some good tips even if it is not the one you accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle it with CSS as it is not possible to style ancestors on descendant `:hover`.
You will need `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to simulate the `:hover` behavior : you can use one function that will check current `body` CSS class  change it to another possible ("white"/"black" background and "black/white" text color in `.body2` and `.body1`) and apply `transition` to the body `background` color change using common for both `body` element selector. See the code below :

***HTML :***

```
<input type="submit" class="loginButtonBodyBG" id="buttonText" value="Log In" onmouseover="g()" onmouseout="g()"/>
```

***CSS :***

```
body{
 transition: background-color 2s ease;
}

.body1{
   background : black;
   color: white;
}

.body2{
   background : white;
   color: black;
 }
```

***JavaScript :***

```
function g(){
    var bbc = document.body.className;
    document.body.className = bbc == 'body1' ? 'body2' : 'body1'
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/63d5R/14/)

Comment: Would you be able to point me in the direction of making it a slower transition between colors upon onmouseover and onmouseout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to change the body background and color of the font on hover on the submit button

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.loginButtonBodyBG').hover(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).parents('body').css({'background':'black','color':'white'});
    }, function(){ 
        jQuery(this).parents('body').css({'background':'white','color':'black'});
    } );                              
});
```